# Bootstrap slider not working: slider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

my Bootstrap slider is not working. I'm not sure why. Here' my HTML where all css and js loading correctly. I get an error in console: `slider is not a function.` I downloaded the latest version of bootstrap slider (using Chrome). The slider, if triggered from console also doesn't work.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/header.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slider();
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Find Vet</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                     <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                Login via
                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                                </div>
                                or
                                 <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                             <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
                                             </label>
                                        </div>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom text-center">
                                New here ? <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="content">
<input type="text" class="" value="" data-slider-min="2" data-slider-max="25" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="25" data-slider-orientation="vertical" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/header.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-side-notes.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/animate.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-formhelpers-min.css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/slider.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-formhelpers-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javasript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javasript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

Typo on the type, missing a 'c' in javascript should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

I'd suggest looking into a good IDE/Editor.